# How to achieve bottom inverted border radius app bar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

here is the `appBar` that i'm trying to achieve,

[image]

here is what i tried, but this is not right method at all, how do i achieve this App bar in flutter

```
Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView(
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 180,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(gradient: AppColor.bgColor),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 140),
                  child: Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 250,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                      color: Colors.white
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

this is not the right method i know, please provide the right method to achieve this app bar, thank you for your time :)

Comment: inner container border radius can be  borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(30.0)),

Comment: @MANISHDAYMA but i need shadow for the container that does look like a black line bottom of the screen cos of the shadow. is there any other way to acheive this app bar?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ShapeBorder.

```dart
class AppBarShape extends OutlinedBorder {
  @override
  OutlinedBorder copyWith({BorderSide? side}) => this; //todo

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    Path path = Path()
      ..fillType = PathFillType.evenOdd
      ..addRect(rect)
      ..addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
        Rect.fromLTWH(rect.left, rect.bottom - 30, rect.width, 30),
        topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
        topRight: Radius.circular(30),
      ));
    return path;
  }

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    return getInnerPath(rect, textDirection: textDirection);
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    /// create shader linear gradient
    canvas.drawPath(getInnerPath(rect), Paint()..color = Colors.blue);
  }

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) => this;
}
```

And use case

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      shape: AppBarShape(),
    ),
    body: SafeArea(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 100),
          Container(
            height: 180,
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: ShapeDecoration(shape: AppBarShape(), shadows: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                blurRadius: 10,
                spreadRadius: 5,
                offset: const Offset(0, 5),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Result

[image]

You can also  implement `PreferredSizeWidget` to a widget for Appbar.

```dart
class F extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
```

For Sliver, use `SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate`.

Comment: For gradient check `Paint().shader`

Comment: and instead of creating your `Path` by "hand" (and your brain of course) you can use already made [roundPolygon](https://gist.github.com/pskink/adf730167a48b750a81f1dd197309312#file-round_polygon-dart-L24) function

Answer (score 0):

```
Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topRight,
            end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            colors: [
              Colors.red,
              Colors.green,
              Colors.blue,
            ],
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 65,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Home',
                    style: MyStyle.bold18,
                  ),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.notifications,
                    size: 18,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: AppColor.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                    top: Radius.circular(35),
                  ),
                ),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  vertical: 20,
                  horizontal: 16,
                ),
                child: child,// your child widget
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```